# Activity Indicator is not visible on xaml page in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, loader, activity-indicator

I have an activity indicator on xaml page. Initially its IsVisible property is false. I have a button on page. When user click on button it calls a web service to get data. I change the value of IsVisible property to true before calling the service so that activity indicator starts to display on page and after successful calling of service I change its value to again false so that it doesn't show any more on page.

But it is not working. I know the actual problem. When we call the web service the UI thread gets block and it doesn't show the activity indicator. 
How I can enable the UI thread when web service gets called so that activity indicator can show on page until we get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your webservice call into an `async` and `await` it.

Depending on how you've structured things you may have to use a `TaskCompletionSource` as the following example demonstrates.

In this example when the button is clicked, the button is made **invisible**, and the `ActivityIndicator` is set to `IsRunning=True` to **show** it.

It then executes your long running task / webservice in the function `ExecuteSomeLongTask` using a `TaskCompletionSource`.

The reason for this is that in our button click code, we have the final lines:-

```
              objActivityIndicator1.IsRunning = false;
              objButton1.IsVisible = true;
```

That **stop** the `ActivityIndicator` from running and showing, and **also** set the button back to a visible state.

If we did not use a `TaskCompletionSource` these lines would execute immediately after calling the `ExecuteSomeLongTask` if it was a normal async method / function, and would result in the `ActivityIndicator` **not** running and the button **still** being visible.

**Example:-**

```
        Grid objGrid = new Grid()
        {
        };

        ActivityIndicator objActivityIndicator1 = new ActivityIndicator();
        objGrid.Children.Add(objActivityIndicator1);

        Button objButton1 = new Button();
        objButton1.Text = "Execute webservice call.";
        objButton1.Clicked += (async (o2, e2) =>
          {
              objButton1.IsVisible = false;
              objActivityIndicator1.IsRunning = true;
              //
              bool blnResult = await ExecuteSomeLongTask();
              //
              objActivityIndicator1.IsRunning = false;
              objButton1.IsVisible = true;
          });
        objGrid.Children.Add(objButton1);

        return objGrid;
```

**Supporting function:-**

```
    private Task<bool> ExecuteSomeLongTask()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> objTaskCompletionSource1 = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        //
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), new Func<bool>(() =>
        {
            objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult(true);
            //
            return false;
        }));
        //
       return objTaskCompletionSource1.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your work in an asynchronous way. Or in other words: Use `Asnyc & Await` to ensure, that you UI works well during the call.

You can find more informations in [the Xamarin Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/).

> async and await are new C# language features that work in conjunction
>   with the Task Parallel Library to make it easy to write threaded code
>   to perform long-running tasks without blocking the main thread of your
>   application.

If you need further asistance, please update your question and post your code or what you have tried so far.